# Testing if Python string variable holds number (int,float) or non-numeric str?

Tags: python

If a Python string variable has had either an integer, floating point number or a non-numeric string placed in it, is there a way to easily test the "type" of that value?

The code below is real (and correct of course):

```
>>> strVar = "145"
>>> print type(strVar)
<type 'str'>
>>>
```

but is there a Python function or other method that will enable me to return 'int' from interrogating strVar set as above

Perhaps something like the nonsense code and results below ...

```
>>> print typeofvalue(strVar)
<type 'int'>
```

or more nonsense:

```
>>> print type(unquote(strVar))
<type 'int'>
```

Comment: Huh... Does `var = "Hello 20"` "contain a number"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
import ast
def type_of_value(var):
    try:
       return type(ast.literal_eval(var))
    except Exception:
       return str
```

Or, if you only want to check for int, change the third line to block inside `try` with:

```
int(var)
return int
```

Comment: Just beat me, but this is probably better.

Comment: You should just catch `ValueError` otherwise you'll swallow the `NameError` when `ast` isn't imported.  +1 nonetheless.

Comment: @sdolan The problem is that literal_eval may raise many different errors... I'll import ast :)

Comment: Like @sdolan pointed out, but also look at catching SyntaxError: "This function raises SyntaxError if the compiled source is invalid, and TypeError if the source contains null bytes."  This is from the docs of compile() which is what this function calls.

Answer (score 6):

I'd do it like this:

```
def typeofvalue(text):
    try:
        int(text)
        return int
    except ValueError:
        pass

    try:
        float(text)
        return float
    except ValueError:
        pass

    return str
```

Answer (score 4):

use .isdigit():

```
In [14]: a = '145'

In [15]: b = 'foo'

In [16]: a.isdigit()
Out[16]: True

In [17]: b.isdigit()
Out[17]: False

In [18]:
```

Comment: Thanks Rafael - have not tested because I did not recognise some of your syntax - but trust that it would work if I did.  As it turns out my integer and floats could be negatives (latitude/longitude).

Comment: My fav (for simple int vs. str cases). But maybe the `In`and `Out` stuff does more harm than good.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if a variable is numeric using the built-in [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) function:

```
isinstance(x, (int, long, float, complex))
```

This also applies to string and unicode literal types:

```
isinstance(x, (str, unicode))
```

For example:

```
def checker(x):
    if isinstance(x, (int, long, float, complex)):
        print "numeric"
    elif isinstance(x, (str, unicode)):
        print "string"
```

---

```
>>> x = "145"
>>> checker(x)
string
>>> x = 145
>>> checker(x)
numeric
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a regular expression

```
def instring (a):

  if re.match ('\d+', a):
    return int(a)
  elsif re.match ('\d+\.\d+', a):
    return float(a)
  else:
    return str(a)
```

Comment: you should add `^[+-]?` and `$` to your regexes... If OP wants scientific notation like `3e+12` you'll have to add `([eE][+-]\d+)?`

Comment: @JBernardo:  point taken...  Also this sounds like a user input; so there should probably be more input validation leading to regexp than just "what type is it".

Comment: Thanks whitey04 - have not tested because I did not recognise some of your syntax - but trust that it would work if I did.

Comment: I can hardly imagine a less Pythonic approach to the task.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short hand to do it without ast import

```
    try:
        if len(str(int(decdata))) == len(decdata): return 'int'
    except Exception:
        return 'not int'
```

Of course 's' is the string you want to evaluate